# wweb.js : got "Client blackbox not found. undefined" when get data client from Map

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

**WhatsAppClientManager.js**
[WhatsAppClientManager.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgFXT.jpg)

**client.js**
[client.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AEPi.png)

**messageController.js**
[messageController.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dp9RL.jpg)

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzRgp.png)

i am trying to initialize the client using "const client = await clientManager.getClient(clientId)"
but instead I get "Client blackbox(client id) not found" like in the picture above

Comment: Please add the relevant code and the error **as text** to the question

Comment: [SOLVED]
I've managed to get a solution for saving on Map. I initiated the Map outside the WhatsAppClientManager class. Not in the constructor anymore.

const clients = new Map();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SOLVED] I've managed to get a solution for saving on Map. I initiated the Map outside the WhatsAppClientManager class. Not in the constructor anymore. const clients = new Map();